# How to create a windows docker image larger than 20GB?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-build

I've been trying to build a large windows docker image for days now but I can't find an answer anywhere that addresses this issue.

I'm not trying to build a production container solution. I'm just trying to create a prototype of my service but run in a windows container. The issue is that my service depends on about 40GBs of data and right now and that data is read from disk. Obviously this is not a great approach and it will have to be refactored before we could ever host the service in a container in production.

I just want a quick and dirty solution of building an image with all this data stored on disk in the container so I can learn more about how the service would run inside a container.

My image structure will end up looking like this:

microsoft/windowsservercore -> mine/data_image -> mine/binary_image

data.dockerfile :

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
WORKDIR /data/
COPY data .
```

Build command:

```
docker build --compress -t mine/data_image -f data.dockerfile .
```

After a while, the build fails with this message:
failed to copy files: failed to copy directory: write \?\Volume{8cf8bb9b-c1dd-46a3-b353-3c2198754bf8}\data: There is not enough space on the disk.

I know this has to do with the windowsfilter disk driver but there is no documentation that I can find online about this driver. It's like it doesn't exist.

Any insights relating to this problem are welcome!

Comment: I really don't think you should put data inside the docker imsge itself. The data should be inside a volume that is shared across versions...

Answer (score 2):

You can override the default 20GB size like this:

```
dockerd --register-service --storage-opt size=60G
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you [can't specify a size for `docker build` yet](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34947).

The ability to specify a size when running a container was added in [Docker CE 17.09](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/34508) so the functionality is at least there. So watch [#34947](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34947) for a resolution which shouldn't be too far away.

I know on Linux the devicemapper storage driver had a `dm.basesize` option you could set on the daemon to modify the volume size all containers started with.  The Windows storage driver might have a similar option?